# How to load/debug a Mono Assembly.LoadFile BadImageFormatException on Mac?

Tags: macos, mono, unity-game-engine, .net-assembly

Summary:

I'm trying to manually load an Assembly in a Mono environment and getting a BadImageFormatException on Mac, but it works fine on Windows. Since Mono is running inside another app, I'm not able to run the app from the command line with debug enabled to get better logging.

Detail:

I wrote some plugins for the Unity3D editor in C#. They have been working for both Mac and Windows for more than a year. I'm now trying to change the way my plugins are loaded from Unity's default "Plugins" directory by loading them manually when my class is called for the first time from another directory (which is in the PATH variable). On Windows I simply call Assembly.LoadFile and it all works fine as before. On Mac, I'm getting a BadImageFormatException error. I thought it might be related to the fact that on Mac the plugin is a bundle.

I tried:

```
Assmebly.LoadFile("MyPlugin")
Assmebly.LoadFile("MyPlugin.bundle")
Assmebly.LoadFile("MyPlugin.bundle/Contents/MacOS/MyPlugin")
```

The first one (just the file name) returns a FileNotFoundException. The other two return BadImageFormatException making me think it found it but something else is wrong.

Is there a way to get more info on what's going wrong? The FusionLog member of the exception is NULL since it's on Mac, I only get the basic message.

Do my plugins need to be built differently somehow on Mac to be manually loaded like this?

Thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 1):

Assembly.LoadFile takes the path to a .NET assembly.

This means that `MyPlugin.bundle` will not work, because it's a directory.

Regarding the last option, that file (assuming it's a file and not a directory) needs to be a .NET assembly - one way to check if that's the case is to run the `file` tool from a Terminal window:

```
$ file MyPlugin.bundle/Contents/MacOS/MyPlugin
```

and it should respond something like this:

```
MyPlugin: PE32 executable for MS Windows (DLL) (console) Intel 80386 32-bit Mono/.Net assembly
```

My guess however is that it's not a .NET assembly, but instead a native (OSX) binary (among other things because .NET assemblies usually have .dll extensions).

Comment: Hi Rolf, sorry for so long to not comment or accept answer. I wanted to check a little more. The code was working for a long time and then only when I changed directories it isn't. I got access to the source code and looked into it and it seems both use native code calls specific for each platform within the Mono VM. There isn't a way to mimic that loading on Mac from managed code only the way they do it from native code side when loading plugin directory. That's why it works on Mac because they load the framework from within the bundle structure (it loads dylib on Mac, not ell).